# Fifo block implementation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

i wrote a fifo in system verilog
i try to push some data to this fifo (i wrote a tb) and when i push data the fifo_wr_ptr, fifo_fre_space,fifo_used_space don't update (only data write to mem[0])

i will be glad for help (why my ptr don't increment by 1 for example)

Thanks alot! 
and here is my simulation that shows my problem:

[image]

i attached my code:

```
module fifo
#(parameter WIDTH = 32,   parameter DEPTH = 64 ) (   clk,   rst_l,   sw_rst,   fifo_din,   fifo_push_en,   fifo_pop_en,   fifo_dout,   fifo_o_full,   fifo_o_empty,   fifo_used_space,   fifo_free_space );




   function integer log2; //can use the $clog2() function
      input [31:0] value;
      reg [31:0]   value_tmp;
      begin      value_tmp = value;      for(log2=0; value_tmp>0; log2=log2+1)
       value_tmp=(value_tmp>>1);
      end    endfunction

localparam DEPTH_LOG2 = log2(DEPTH);

//interface  input clk; input rst_l; input sw_rst; input[WIDTH-1:0] fifo_din; input fifo_push_en; input fifo_pop_en; output logic[WIDTH-1:0] fifo_dout; output logic fifo_o_full; output logic fifo_o_empty; output logic[DEPTH_LOG2-1:0] fifo_used_space; output logic[DEPTH_LOG2-1:0] fifo_free_space; logic debug_flag; //internal logic logic[WIDTH-1:0] mem[DEPTH_LOG2-1:0]; logic[DEPTH_LOG2-1:0] fifo_rd_ptr,fifo_wr_ptr;

assign fifo_o_empty = (fifo_used_space==0); assign fifo_o_full  = (fifo_free_space==0);


always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_l) begin    if(~rst_l) begin 
     fifo_free_space <= DEPTH;
     fifo_used_space <= 0;
     fifo_rd_ptr <= 0;
     fifo_wr_ptr <= 0;
     debug_flag <=0 ;

  end else if (~sw_rst) begin
     fifo_free_space <= DEPTH;
     fifo_used_space <= 0;
     fifo_rd_ptr <= 0;
     fifo_wr_ptr <= 0;
     debug_flag <= 0;

 end else if(fifo_push_en==1 && fifo_o_full==0 && fifo_pop_en==0) begin //the fifo isn't full and can perform the write trasaction (and no read transaction)
     fifo_used_space <= fifo_used_space + 1;
     fifo_free_space <= fifo_free_space - 1;
     mem[fifo_wr_ptr]<= fifo_din;
     debug_flag <= 1;
     if(fifo_wr_ptr == (DEPTH - 1)) 
        fifo_wr_ptr <= 0;
     else
        fifo_wr_ptr++;


     end else if (fifo_pop_en==1 && fifo_o_empty==0 && fifo_push_en==0) begin // the fifo isn't empty and can perform the read trasaction (and no write trasaction)
     fifo_used_space <= fifo_used_space - 1;
     fifo_free_space <= fifo_free_space + 1;
     fifo_dout       <= mem[fifo_rd_ptr];
     if(fifo_rd_ptr == (DEPTH - 1)) begin 
        fifo_rd_ptr  <= 0;
     end else begin 
        fifo_rd_ptr  <= fifo_rd_ptr + 1;
     end  end else begin

     fifo_rd_ptr     <= fifo_rd_ptr;
     //fifo_wr_ptr     <= fifo_wr_ptr;
     //fifo_dout       <= fifo_dout;
     //fifo_used_space <= fifo_used_space;
     fifo_free_space <= fifo_free_space;   end end

endmodule
```

and here is the tb code:

```
`define WIDTH 32
`define DEPTH 64

module fifo_tb();


   function integer log2; //can use the $clog2() function
      input [31:0] value;
      reg [31:0]   value_tmp;
      begin
     value_tmp = value;
     for(log2=0; value_tmp>0; log2=log2+1)
       value_tmp=(value_tmp>>1);
      end
   endfunction


localparam DEPTH_LOG2 = log2(`DEPTH);


logic clk,rst_l,sw_rst,fifo_push_en,fifo_pop_en,fifo_o_full,fifo_o_empty;
logic[`WIDTH-1:0] fifo_din,fifo_dout,tempdata;
logic[DEPTH_LOG2-1:0] fifo_used_space,fifo_free_space;

fifo #(`WIDTH,`DEPTH) ff(.clk(clk), .rst_l(rst_l), .sw_rst(sw_rst), .fifo_din(fifo_din),
            .fifo_push_en(fifo_push_en), .fifo_pop_en(fifo_pop_en),
            .fifo_dout(fifo_dout), .fifo_o_full(fifo_o_full), .fifo_o_empty(fifo_o_empty),
            .fifo_used_space(fifo_used_space), .fifo_free_space(fifo_free_space) );

initial 
begin
   clk =0;
   rst_l = 0;
   sw_rst= 0;
   fifo_push_en=0;
   fifo_pop_en=0;
   fifo_din=0;
   tempdata=0;

   #15 rst_l=1;
   #1  sw_rst=1;

   push(10);
   push(20);
   push(30);
   push(40);
   pop(tempdata);
   push(tempdata);


end

always 
   #5 clk=~clk;


task push;
   input[`WIDTH-1:0] data;
   if(fifo_o_full) 
      $display("--- Cannot push: Buffer full ----");
    else begin 
      $display("Pushed: ",data);
      @(posedge clk);
      fifo_din = data;
      fifo_push_en=1;
      @(posedge clk);
      fifo_push_en=0;
   end
endtask

task pop;
   output [`WIDTH-1:0] data;

   if(fifo_o_empty) 
      $display("Cannot pop: buffer empty ---");
      else begin
         @(posedge clk);
         fifo_pop_en=1;
         @(posedge clk);
         fifo_pop_en=0;
         data=fifo_dout;
         $display("----- Poped : ",data);
      end
 endtask


 endmodule
```

Comment: no complication errors for me..

Comment: @IdanRahamim fifo_wr_ptr in your fifo module is commented out how did it compile for you? It should throw an error

Comment: @IdanRahamim I cannot compile it either. vcs throws 15 errors. You need to compile it with a good compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Taking aside the oddity related to pointer incrementation, the code itself is confusing and difficult to deal with. Pasting reference FIFO module that should do the job, this also should help you to grasp on basics of coding style.

```
//----------------------------------------------------
// Module Name: fifo_sync.v
//----------------------------------------------------
// Description: generic sync FIFO module
//----------------------------------------------------

module fifo_sync #
(
    parameter FIFO_DATA_WIDTH = 'd32,
    parameter FIFO_PTR_WIDTH = 'd6
)
(
    //------------------------------------------------
    // Inputs
    //------------------------------------------------
    input                       clk,
    input                       rst_n,
    input                       wr_en,
    input [FIFO_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] wr_data,
    input                       rd_en,

    //------------------------------------------------
    // Outputs
    //------------------------------------------------
    output reg [FIFO_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] rd_data,
    output                           stat_full,
    output                           stat_empty,
    output     [ FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-1:0] stat_occupancy
);

    //------------------------------------------------
    // Local Parameters
    //------------------------------------------------
    localparam FIFO_DEPTH = 2**(FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-1);

    //------------------------------------------------
    // Internal Register(s)/Wire(s)/Integer(s)
    //------------------------------------------------
    reg [ FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-1:0] wr_ptr;
    reg [ FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-1:0] rd_ptr;
    reg [FIFO_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] fifo_array [FIFO_DEPTH-1:0];
    integer int_i;

    //------------------------------------------------
    // Write Pointer Logic
    //------------------------------------------------
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    begin: p_wr_ptr
        if (!rst_n)
            wr_ptr <= {FIFO_PTR_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        else if (wr_en & !stat_full)
            wr_ptr <= wr_ptr + 1'b1;
    end

    //------------------------------------------------
    // Read Pointer Logic
    //------------------------------------------------
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    begin: p_rd_ptr
        if (!rst_n)
            rd_ptr <= {FIFO_PTR_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        else if (rd_en & !stat_empty)
            rd_ptr <= rd_ptr + 1'b1;
    end

    //------------------------------------------------
    // Status Interface
    //------------------------------------------------

    // FIFO full status flag
    assign stat_full = (wr_ptr[FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-1] ^ rd_ptr[FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-1]) & (wr_ptr[FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-2:0] == rd_ptr[FIFO_PTR_WIDTH-2:0]);
    // FIFO empty status flag
    assign stat_empty = (wr_ptr == rd_ptr);
    // FIFO occupancy status
    assign stat_occupancy = wr_ptr - rd_ptr;

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // FIFO Write
    //-----------------------------------------------
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    begin: p_fifo_write
        if (!rst_n)
            for (int_i = 0; int_i < FIFO_DEPTH - 1; int_i = int_i + 1)
                fifo_array[int_i] <= {FIFO_DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        else if (wr_en & !stat_full)
            fifo_array[wr_ptr] <= wr_data;
    end

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // FIFO Read
    //-----------------------------------------------
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    begin: p_fifo_read
        if (!rst_n)
            rd_data <= {FIFO_DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        else if (rd_en & !stat_empty)
            rd_data <= fifo_array[rd_ptr];
    end

endmodule
```